# Use ffi (-napi) in NodeJS on Windows

Tags: node.js, dll, ffi, msvcrt

I am trying to hook into a DLL from node and I have learned about ffi. I am more of a GNU/Linux person than MS. For me, the regular ffi package did not build correctly, but ffi-napi did. I tried to follow the simple test routine at [the npm package site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-napi) that hooks into ceil(double). The example code there links the libm library, which is more familiar to me, but that is not how Microsoft does things. As far as I can tell, this function is in msvcrt.dll. I did the following in the node app shell:

```
ffi = require('ffi-napi')
msvcrt = ffi.Library('C:\\Windows\\System32\\msvcrt', {'ceil': [ 'double', [ 'double' ] ]})
```

After pressing enter on the second line, there is a lot of text dumped to the node shell and then the app closes. Has anyone used ffi on Windows? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I feel a bit silly but I was just being too exact. It worked with:

```
ffi = require('ffi-napi')
msvcrt = ffi.Library('msvcrt', {'ceil': [ 'double', [ 'double' ] ]})
msvcrt.ceil(1.5)
```

With a write of '2' to the console. I guess I am a bit paranoid, because on Linux searching /lib and /usr/lib would be automatic, but Windows is weird and gives every program its own directory. I guess ffi on Windows does default to searching the Windows\System32 directory though.

This also has me worried because I don't know why a fully qualified path would cause it to crash. If anyone has any input on that, I would love to hear it.

UPDATE:
I got it to work with a fully qualified path by using:

```
msvcrt = ffi.Library('\\Windows\\System32\\msvcrt', {'ceil': [ 'double', [ 'double' ] ]})
```

so this allows accessing DLLs anywhere on the same "drive letter" (which for my use right now is enough). If I find an answer for crossing to a different drive I will update this again.

Answer (score 0):

For better use of ffi in node.js, you can use ffi-rs which implement ffi for node.js by rust .https://github.com/zhangyuang/node-ffi-rs